# How to remove a notification from a single user and it not be removed for other users that have not viewed it?

Tags: python, django

Using Django, I've got a task manager and one to many users can be assigned a task. For each user assigned this task, there is a notification that shows up for them. Currently, if 1 of those users clicks the notification to bring them to the details of the task, it will remove that notification for all users. I need it to be removed from only that one user that has read the details so that the notification stays active for the rest of the users.

Here is my view where this is happening

```
def task_detail(request, pk):
    # task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    task = Task.objects.filter(id=pk, assigned_to=request.user, read=False).first()
    note_queryset = TaskNote.objects.filter(task_id=task.pk).order_by('-created_date')
    note_form = TaskNoteForm(request.POST or None)
    files = TaskFile.objects.filter(task=task)

    # check if logged in user is in the list of assigned_to
    # if request.user in task.assigned_to.all():
        # user_task = Task.objects.get(id=task.id, assigned_to=request.user)
          
    task.read = True
    task.save(update_fields=['read'])

    if request.POST.get("add-note"):
        if note_form.is_valid():
            note_form = note_form.save(commit=False)
            note_form.created_by = request.user
            note_form.task_id = int(task.pk)
            note_form.save()
            return redirect(f'/task_manager/task/{task.pk}')

    context = {
        "task": task,
        "note_queryset": note_queryset,
        "note_form": note_form,
        "files": files,
    }

    return render(request, "task_manager/task_detail.html", context)
```

Edit: I have gone ahead and created an additional model to be used as a "through" model. Still working on figuring out how to solve my issue though. Not entirely sure it was neccessary that I made this new model.
The Model - edited

```
class Task(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='cb_user_task')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.ForeignKey(TaskStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=4)
    priority = models.ForeignKey(TaskPriority, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='TaskAssignee')
    # read_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='read_tasks')
    completed_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)

    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='ub_user_task')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class TaskAssignee(models.Model):
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='t_assignee')
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='a_task')
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    read_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='read_by')
```

The context processor function - this is what is displaying the notifications from the application im working in to the dashboard page. It count's unread notifications and shows the five most recent and shows who created and date created.

```
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        user_tasks = Task.objects.filter(assigned_to=user).order_by('-created_date')[:5]
        task_count = Task.objects.filter(assigned_to=user, read=False).count()

        return {
            "user_tasks": user_tasks,
            "task_count": task_count,
        }

    else:
        return {}
```

I have tried different queries and logic but it seems the result is either it removes the notification from all users or the notification stays even after the details have been read.
Edit: Trying something else with a through model. Still no luck yet